# I am trying to create a base class and derived class that displays functions on a form and need help to fix code

Tags: vb.net

Here are the project instructions:

> The main form has eight label controls, two textbox controls and four buttons. Customer Name and Account are static value. You enter Starting Account Balance and Transaction Amount. Clicking on Deposit button adds the Transaction Amount to Starting Account Balance and displays in Account Balance label. Clicking on Withdraw button checks to make sure there is sufficient fund in Starting Account Balance, if not it displays a message: The amount to withdraw exceeds account balance.
>   Clear button clears Starting Account Balance, Transaction Amount, and Account Balance. Exit button closes the form.

Here is my code for Base Class ACCOUNT and Derived Class BANK ACCOUNT:

```vb
Public Class Account
    Public StartBalance As Decimal
    Public Transaction As Decimal
    Public AccountBalance As Decimal
    Public Property txtStartBalance() As Decimal
        Get
            Return StartBalance
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            StartBalance = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub New(ByVal txtStartBalance As Decimal, txtTransaction As Decimal, txtAccountBalance As Decimal)
        StartBalance = txtStartBalance
        Transaction = txtTransaction
        AccountBalance = txtAccountBalance
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class BankAccount
    Inherits Account
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub
    Public Function MakeDeposit(ByVal txtAccountBalance.text As Decimal)
        AccountBalance = StartBalance + Transaction
        txtAccountBalance.text = AccountBalance
    End Function
    Public Function MakeWithdraw(ByVal txtAccountBalance.text As Decimal)
        If Transaction > StartBalance Then
            MessageBox.Show("The amount to withdraw exceeds account balance.")
        Else
            AccountBalance = StartBalance - Transaction
            txtAccountBalance.text = AccountBalance
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Here is my FORM code:

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        txtStartBalance.Clear()
        txtTransaction.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDeposit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeposit.Click
        Dim MyAccount As New BankAccount()
        If txtStartBalance.Text = Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Error! Enter Starting Account Balance")
        ElseIf txtTransaction.Text = Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Error! Enter Transaction Amount")
        Else
            MakeDeposit()
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnWithdraw_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnWithdraw.Click
        Dim MyAccount As New Account(byVal txtStartBalance.Text As Decimal, byVal txtTransaction.Text As Decimal))
            txtAccountBalance.txt = MakeWithdraw()
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is my form design:

[image]

Comment: You have described your assignment and code, but you haven't asked a question.

Comment: Further to what @GSerg said, you need to be specific about what you expect to see and what you actually do see, including where in the code the difference occurs. You need to be very specific about one particular issue. If there are multiple issues or something too general, you need to narrow it down.

Comment: sorry, I will be more specific in my posts. I have been working on this for days so this was a last resort. I think I grasp the inheritance concept but for the life of me I do not know how to get the functionality of the input of numbers to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a class variables like `Public StartBalance As Decimal`  are called fields as opposed to Properties. Fields are normally `Private` and hold the data of the class. The Public Properties expose the class's data through property procedures; what you have written with the `Get`, `Set` code. Up to date versions of Visual Studio write the Property procedure, and backer field for you. All you have to write is `Public Property StartBalance`. The rest is hidden but it works the same.

Your problem with the `BankAccount` class is Sub New. For `MyBase.New` to function it must have the parameters that the base is looking for.

You don't want your class to be dependent upon the User Interface controls. The class may be used in other programs with a different UI, maybe a web application. Message boxes in the class wouldn't work in a web app. As long as the methods of the class receive parameters of the proper type it will function without caring where the parameters came from.

Whenever you have user input you need to validate that it is  correct. I moved that to a separate `Function` so the event procedure wouldn't be too long.

I made a single event procedure for both transaction buttons (note the `Handles` clause) because most of the code is the same. A property of the class instance (`BankCustomer.CurrentBalance`) contains the value you want for the balance label.

```vb
Public Class Account
    Public Property CurrentBalance As Decimal
    Public Property StartBalance As Decimal
    Public Property CustomerName As String
    Public Property AccountNumber As Integer
    Public Sub New(BegBalance As Decimal, AcctNum As Integer, Name As String)
        StartBalance = BegBalance
        CurrentBalance = StartBalance
        CustomerName = Name
        AccountNumber = AcctNum
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class BankAccount
    Inherits Account
    Public Sub New(BegBalance As Decimal, AcctNum As Integer, Name As String)
        MyBase.New(BegBalance, AcctNum, Name)
    End Sub
    Public Sub MakeDeposit(ByVal TransAmount As Decimal)
        CurrentBalance += TransAmount
    End Sub
    Public Function MakeWithdraw(ByVal TransAmount As Decimal) As Boolean
        If TransAmount > CurrentBalance Then
            Return False
        Else
            CurrentBalance -= TransAmount
            Return True
        End If
    End Function
End Class

'In the Form

Private BankCustomer As BankAccount

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    txtStartBalance.Clear()
    txtTransaction.Clear()
    'Clear the labels too
    BankCustomer = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub TransactionButtons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeposit.Click, btnWithdraw.Click
    If Not ValidateInput() Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If BankCustomer Is Nothing Then
        BankCustomer = New BankAccount(CDec(txtStartBalance), CInt(txtAccountNumber.Text), txtCustomerName.Text)
    End If
    Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    If btn.Name = "btnDeposit" Then
        BankCustomer.MakeDeposit(CDec(txtTransaction.Text))
    Else
        If Not BankCustomer.MakeWithdraw(CDec(txtTransaction.Text)) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, cannot make withdrawal, amount exceeds current balance.")
        End If
    End If
    lblAccountBalance = BankCustomer.CurrentBalance.ToString
End Sub

Private Function ValidateInput() As Boolean
    Dim bool = False
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCustomerName.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill in Customer Name")
        Return False
    End If
    If Not Integer.TryParse(txtAccountNumber.Text, Nothing) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number for Account Number")
        Return False
    End If
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtStartBalance.Text, Nothing) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid Start Balance")
        Return False
    End If
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtTransaction.Text, Nothing) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid Transaction amount")
        Return False
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I have been trying to grasp this for days, and now I finally understand. I can follow the Boolean logic as well, I prefer that to what I was trying.

Comment: OK, nearly have it. I integrated the Boolean validation and I corrected the Class coding so there are no errors there. I have put the Customer Name and Account Number as static data in the textboxes on the form so they are not part of the coding. I am still getting 2 errors on my FORM: "Argument not specified for parameter 'CurrentBalance' of 'Public Sub New(CurrentBalance as decimal)" and " 'CurrentBalance' is not a member of 'BankAccount"

Comment: @Xochitl  There is no CurrentBalance As Decimal in any of the Sub New in my classes. That is a calculated property set in code, not something passed to the New method.